# Exclude objects from camera in Three.js

Tags: camera, three.js, raytracing

i'm wondering if it's possible to hide a list of objects from a camera (used to build a reflaction map over a plan, simulating the water).
So basicly i'd want to hide a list of objects from the water reflaction.

The Object3D.visible property will of course hide the object for the main camera too so it's useless.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before you update the reflection camera, hide the objects, when the reflection map is rendered, make them visible again.

without your current code i wouldnt be able to provide you with example code since there are several ways to accomplish reflection.

Comment: Yes i was already thinking to a similar solution but i didn't know how to do it. Now i've found the code that manages the rendering of the cloned scene and i'm making a simple cycle through an excludedObjects array BEFORE and AFTER the renderer.render() function. Many thanks for your support anyway ;)